# Excel Count IF 3 conditons apply

Tags: excel

Hi I am working on an employee schedule that currently looks like:
[image]
Where "# of employees on by hour" is a count of Employees that will be on at the Hour in C9:C33. 1 denotes working that day. I manually entered the numbers in the highlighted area but that's what I need to get.   So Logic is `Count IF C*>=(B2:B7) & C*<(C2:C7) & (D2:D7)>0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a =COUNTIFS():
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$7, "<=" & $C#, $C$2:$C$7, ">" & $C#, D$2:D$7, ">0")
```

Comment: What are the `*`'s doing?

Comment: Same thing as what he's doing in his question, placeholding, though I'll replace them with # for clarity

Comment: Yes. they were essentially wildcards. Thanks Aleksander, that worked. I do have a new problem though with Overnight employees. Will return with a new Q if I cant figure it out...